# Xcode memory leak

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak when I call the following method

```
- (NSArray *) children
{
NSArray *children = [node objectForKey:TFHppleNodeChildrenKey];
NSMutableArray *hpple = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[children count]];
for(NSDictionary *child in children) {
    [hpple addObject:[[TFHppleElement alloc] initWithNode:child]];
    [child release];
}
return hpple;
}
```

I get a memory leak on `TFHppleElement`, I alloc this but I not sure of the best way to release it in this context? The `TFHppleElement` `initWithNode` looks like this:

```
- (id) initWithNode:(NSDictionary *) theNode
    {
 if (!(self = [super init]))
  return nil;

[theNode retain];
node = theNode;

return self;
 }
```

Comment: `[child release]` should not be there. Whoever adds the child the to the array children should not have an extra retain on it and you will have crash once once you fix the TFHppleElement leak.

Comment: thanks joe, you are right that is what happened. I have now removed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply autorelease that object to make runtime responsible for releasing it:

```
[hpple addObject:[[[TFHppleElement alloc] initWithNode:child] autorelease]];
```

Comment: @user598241 Just to add to this, you can easily add an `elementWithNode:` convenience method to `TFHppleElement` that returns an autoreleased object.

Answer (score 0):

Not shure cause I haven't started Objective-C not to long ago but I would to autoreleas directly when you alloc it.  That will prevent you from having to manage the release and making  the runtime manage the release of it.

```
- (NSArray *) children
{
NSArray *children = [node objectForKey:TFHppleNodeChildrenKey];
NSMutableArray *hpple = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[children count]];
for(NSDictionary *child in children) {
    [hpple addObject:[[[TFHppleElement alloc] initWithNode:child] autorelease]];
    [child release];
}
return hpple;
}
```